# How to set time to sweden?

Tags: php, timezone

I have a radio site, and there is a module called "upNext" and that module will show my visitors when next DJ is coming.

BUT it's wrong time on the site.

http://sabfm.org//staff/_frontend/upnext.php is showing from 10:00 but my time in Sweden are soon 13:00. How do I fix that?

I have som code:

```
<?php
    // Include the required glob.php file
    require_once( "../_inc/glob.php" );

    // Grab today's date using PHP date()
    $today_date = date( 'N' );

    // Grab the current hour
    $now_hour = date( 'H' );

    // Now we have the current hour, we add one to get the next hour
    $next_hour = $now_hour + 1;

    if ( $next_hour == 24 ) {

        // It's midnight on the next day
        $next_date = $today_date + 1;
        $next_hour = "0";
    }
    else {

    // It's the same day
    $next_date = $today_date;
}
```

And in globe.php I have:

```
session_start();
    putenv( "TZ=UTC" );
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the timezone

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Stockholm");
```

For more information about timezones, please checkout this link:
[PHP Timezones](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_timezones.asp)